# Indexing by given values

Tags: sas

I have a binary variable for each id like this:

```
ID Binary wanted(index)
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 0 3
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 0 1
3 1 0
3 0 1
......................
```

So, assuming I have only first two variables, how I can generate third wanted(index)?
Note: Within each id, if binary before 1 is 0 then index is 0, then, when reaches 1, index starts from 0 and assigns index counts for each 0 after 1.
For instance, for ID 3 there are not 0 before 1 at binary, therefore it starts indexing directly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` function and automatic `first.` variable to test for the conditions for incrementing your sequence value.

Example:

```
data have;
input id flag seqwant;
datalines;
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 0 3
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 0 1
3 1 0
3 0 1
4 1 0
5 0 0 
5 1 0 
5 0 1
;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  if first.id then
    seqcomp = 0 ;

  if (lag(flag) and not first.id) or seqcomp then 
    seqcomp + 1;
run;
```

Note: *variable* + *expression* is the syntax for the `SUM` operator which implicitly causes *variable* to be `retain`ed.